# Физический адрес камеры в Linux

Tags: java

Пытаюсь получить изображение с камеры с помощью JMF. Дело в том, что `MediaLocator` просит физический адрес камеры, а всё то, что я находил в интернете написано про `vfw:Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32):0`, а это для windows. Как узнать адрес для `MediaLocator` в **Linux**.

Вот мой код:

```
import javax.media.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {

Player player;

NewJFrame() {
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            player.stop();
            player.deallocate();
            player.close();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    setSize(640, 480);
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    String mediaFile = "vfw://video0";
    try {
        MediaLocator mlr = new MediaLocator(mediaFile);
        player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mlr);
        player.setRate(100);
        if (player.getVisualComponent() != null) {
            panel.add("Center", player.getVisualComponent());
        }
        if (player.getControlPanelComponent() != null) {
            panel.add("South", player.getControlPanelComponent());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got exception " + e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewJFrame m = new NewJFrame();
    m.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v4l://0` может сработать. А надежнее - `CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null)` и разбирать то, что он вернет.